# duplicate string resource in strings.xml android

Tags: android, xml

Are there other ways to check for duplicate string resource in Android?

say I have these 2 strings:

```
<!-- some other strings -->
<string name="A">I'm A</string>
<string name="A">I'm A</string>
<!-- some other strings -->
```

In my Eclipse, this doesn't cause any error or warnings, even if I tried using lint it does not show up. How can I see such problems then?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: well, I want a way to check for duplicated string resource to eliminate them. A colleague of mine tried to build my project using Android Studio and was not able to do so due to this problem.

Comment: you will get a error resource entry already defined here

Comment: I was expecting that kind of error but the problem is, that does not appear at all

Comment: Clean your project and check.

Comment: What if i want to check for the value instead? `<!-- some other strings -->
<string name="A">I'm A</string>
<string name="B">I'm A</string>
<!-- some other strings -->`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In eclipse:

1. Open your project properties
2. Select Android Lint Preferences
3. Make sure the DuplicateDefinition flag is selected.

This will pop up a warning each time you have a duplicate resource in one of your resource files.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Properties , in **Android Lint preferences** section you can set warning/error on Duplicate definition on resources