# Duplicate Resources Error

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I am making an app that has two separate log ins that you have to enter your info in depending on which button you press. The two log ins have different ids for the info. For one of the log ins it says: 7th_email and then 7th_Password but then for the other log in it says: 8th_email and then 8th_Password. 
I don't see where the error duplicate resources error is coming from.

Here's the code;

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.novaschool.novaschoolapp.Seventh_Grade_Login">
<!-- Login progress -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/login_status"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Login form -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/7th_email"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:text="Enter Your Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/7th_password"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:text="Enter your Password" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/7th_sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Enter"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please paste your code here

Comment: Please post code and error log if any.

Comment: This is half code, I think error is in second half, Please paste full .xml file.

Comment: clean your project.. and if the error persists, make a search for the id that is defined as being repeated in the entire project.

Comment: clean and build your project then run. If still getting error post your complete code.

Comment: i did clean it and then re-ran it but the error is still there

Comment: @user3314574 copy and paste the project in another location and the load it to your IDE.

Comment: @Ram should i paste the xml file in a folder that is in the same folder as the other log-in?

Comment: @user3314574 There is no problem in your code..I think you changed the IDE work space it may cause these kind of problem.So you import your project in different directory.

Comment: @user3314574 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374651/duplicate-string-resource-in-strings-xml-android

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have created an alias with the same ID as an existing resource in the same directory.If not, then restart your IDE or clean and rebuild the project.You copy and paste the project in another location and the load it to your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes when I switch between version control branches.

> **Build -> Clean Project**

menu option usually sorts out this problem in my case.